# Have vim makeprg inherit the host shell's environment

Tags: vim

I'm using vim to edit a Linux kernel. My environment uses a lot of variables and functions defined for this and for other purposes, including a bash function to compile the kernel. So what I normally do is:

1. `vim file.c`
2. edit
3. ctrl+z
4. run compilation function
5. read through errors
6. `fg`
7. fix errors.

I'd like to replace this tedious process with `:make`, and browse through the errors with `:copen`. The problem is that to compile, I need my entire environment... I *could* write a script that sets up the environment each time and then calls the compilation function, and call this script from :make, but that will add a few seconds overhead to each :make call to set up the environment.

So my question is: can `:make` inherit the environment variables/functions from the shell from which it's spawned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process relationship looks like this:

```
bash → vim → bash → make
```

If you want to have `make` inherit the environment from the initial shell (that launched Vim), you have to `export` all those variables (and functions with `export -f funcname`) *in the initial shell*. Either add `export` to the environment definitions, or (if you cannot modify those) write a shell script that you *source* (`source scriptname`) from Bash before invoking Vim.

You can check whether a variable has been properly exported from within Vim via

```
:echo $VARNAME
```

Comment: I can't add export to all my build environment vars/functions, unfortunately. Can I re-initialize my build environment in vim? Will I have to do this every time I call makeprg? That is, each time I call makeprg, does vim spawn a bash shell?

Comment: I wrote a script that sets up the build environment and runs the compile script, and I set that script as makeprg in vim. It works, but it would be great to avoid the overhead of setting up the build environment every time I call :make. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to _add_ export at the definition; you can export them later on (inside the same shell, that's why I said to _source_ any script that does this).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to launch `make` is to have another shell watch a set of files or directory and kick off a command when any file is changed. Every time you `:w`, you'll kick off the make command in that other shell.

There are a number of approaches to this method, as outlined in https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

To keep it simple on linux machines, you can use `inotifywait`:

```
while true; do
    change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create /tmp/path/to/directory/)
    echo "something happened!"
    make
done
```

You'll need another command on OS X since it doesn't support `inotifywait`. The superuser question outlines some possible approaches for OS X.

Although, this doesn't resolve being able to open the errors using `:copen`.

Comment: Thanks. This is useful to know in general, but I'd really like to be able to use the :copen feature.

Comment: If you redirect / `tee` the output of the separate make command into a file, you can `:cfile filename` that inside Vim. That would be quite similar to using `:copen`.